# Exploding a string, only at the last occurrence of the explode match

Tags: php, explode

I'm trying to explode a string, but I need it to explode only at the last `'and'` instead of every `'and'`. Is there a way to do that?

```
<?php

$string = "one and two and three and four and five";
$string = explode(" and ", $string);

print_r($string);

?>
```

**Result:**

Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three [3] => four [4] => five )

**Need Result:**

Array ( [0] => one and two and three and four [1] => five )

Comment: @chris85 I thought maybe there was a pre-built function. I guess I'll just write my own function to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went a little more simplistic in my approach, using `preg_match_all()` with a simple regex instead:

```
$string = "one and two and three and four and five";
$pattern = '/(\w+\s)+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$length = strlen($matches[0][0]);

echo $matches[0][0]; // 'one and two and three and four and'
echo substr($string, $length); // 'five'
```

The only issue here is the first match still has a trailing 'and' which could be gotten rid of, if need be, with a little simple coding. If your want more complex regex you could use positive look aheads and negative look behinds.

Comment: Yeah. Check out my function. It doesn't have a trailing 'and'.

Comment: Cool - it's more verbose than what I am doing here @frosty

Comment: Well, good thing is that it's a function, so this is first and last time I'll ever have to write it again.

Comment: True, I could create this as a function. That's the beautiful thing about code :)

Comment: Personally, any time I have anything in my code that repeats at least once, I'll write a function for it. That cuts the code in at least half, and it makes coding a lot simpler. I got to say, that functions are probably my favorites in coding.

Answer (score 6):

This seems easy enough to do using just basic string functions.

```
$x = strrpos($string, ' and ');
$s2 = array(substr($string, 0, $x), substr($string, $x + 5));
```

Comment: Well, yes. Is that not what you were going for?

Comment: Sure, but my function works for every word, no matter of length. Check it out.

Comment: I only intended this to illustrate a concept. I believe the concept should work just as well within a function.

Comment: 5 => &nbsp;and&nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `preg_split`:

### Single-character delimiter

```
$string = "one,two,three,four,five";
$delimiter = ",";

// The regexp will look like this:  /,([^,]+)$/   
$array = preg_split("/".$delimiter."([^".$delimiter."]+)$/", $string,
  -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($array);
```

The regular expression matches the last delimiter with the last item, but captures only the item so that it's kept in the results thanks to PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE.

PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY is there because, I'm not sure why, the split gives an empty string at the end.

### Multi-character delimiter

The regular expression has to be adapted here, using a negative look-around (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/587815)):

```
$string = "one and two and three and four and five";
$delimiter = " and ";

$array = preg_split("/$delimiter((?(?!$delimiter).)*$)/", $string,
  -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($array);
```

`(?(?!$delimiter).)*` means: match only characters that do no start the word `$delimiter`. The first `?` prevents capturing an additional group.

Comment: In the end I guess using preg_split is probably not the best idea in this case…

Answer (score 0):

I donot know if there is any other quick way for solving that need but you may try the code below;

```
$string = "one and two and three and four and five";
$stringArray = explode(" and ", $string);
$stringArrayItemCount = count($stringArray);
//Keep your last item
$stringArrayLastItem = $stringArray[$stringArrayItemCount-1];
//Remove last item from your array
unset($stringArray[$stringArrayItemCount-1]);
//Create new array imploding existing one + last item of your old array
$stringArray = array(implode(" and ",$stringArray),$stringArrayLastItem);

print_r($stringArray);
```

A working version of this example: http://ideone.com/qdZFtk

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a function to do this:

```
<?php

$string = "one and two and three and four and five";
$string = explodeLast(" and ", $string);

echo $string;

function explodeLast($explodeAt, $string) {

$explode = explode($explodeAt, $string);
$count = count($explode);
$counter = 0;
$string = null;

while ($counter < $count-1) {

if ($counter < $count-2) {
$string .= $explode[$counter].$explodeAt;
} //end of if ($counter < $count-2)
else {
$string .= $explode[$counter];
} //end of else not ($counter < $count-2)

$counter++;
} //end of while ($counter < $count)

return $string;

} //end of function explodeLast($explode, $explodeAt)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$str = 'one and two and three and four and five';
$breakWord = ' and ';

$output = str_split($str, strrpos($str, $breakWord) + strlen($breakWord));

var_dump($output);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0149b3ff973485befe97a1c6b241a6764bd2f289

EDIT - regexp use:

```
<?php
$str = 'one and two and three and four and the last part is actually longer than the first part';
$pattern = "/(.+) and (?!.* and )(.+)/";
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bc68f46fe594e360134bdca256e5916a2f42f74

Comment: I thought about this too, but it runs into problems when `$str = 'one and two and three and four and the last part is actually longer than the first part';`

Comment: How about this?

    <?php
    $str = 'one and two and three and four and the last part is actually longer than the first part';
    $breakWord = ' and ';
    $breakpoint = (int) strrpos($str, $breakWord);

    $output = [
        substr($str, 0, $breakpoint),
        substr($str, $breakpoint + strlen($breakWord))
    ];

    var_dump($output);

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96ae233d75a0eaac78c511aecb2738134f761ca2

Comment: Yeah - I saw it too in this thread after posting this ... but this is "new" :)

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bc68f46fe594e360134bdca256e5916a2f42f74